# Representation of the group of automorphisms on the holomorphic forms

Tags: riemann-surfaces, rt.representation-theory

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface and $G = Aut(X)$ be its group of automorphisms (biholomorphisms between $X$ and $X$). It is known that $G$ acts on the space $Harm(X)$ of all harmonic forms and also on the space $Omega(X)$ of all holomorphic forms.

We know that $Harm(X)$ is a direct sum of $Omega(X)$ and its conjugate.

Now, if we know the representation of $G$ on $Harm(X)$ (by this I mean we have a matrix for each element of $G$), how can we find matrices for the representation of $G$ on $Omega(X)\ ?$

ADDED: I am assuming we have no information about $Omega(X)$ or $Harm(X)$. We just know the genus of $X$, $G$ (with a multiplication table) and the representation of $G$ on $Harm(X)$ (the matrices associated to each element of the group).

Comment: 1.  Is it obvious that the isomorphism class of Omega(X) as a C[G]-module is determined by the isomorphism class of Harm(X)?

2.  On the other hand:  when you say you have "matrices associated to each element of the group," it sounds like you have more than a description of the isomorphism class of Harm(X) as C[G]-module, but rather have the action of G on an explicit basis of harmonic forms.  Or is what you have the action of G on an explicit basis for the first homology?

3.  In any event, I believe this issue was discussed in De Jong & Noot's paper "Jacobians with complex multiplications."

Comment: 1. I don't know but I saw this claim in Streit's paper "Homology, Belyĭ functions and canonical curves"

2. I really just have the matrices. I don't have a basis for any of the spaces.

3. Thanks for the reference. I will take a look at it.